# How can I set the text of the TextView within a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, textview, dynamically-generated

I have created a custom LinearLayout through program which have a custom TextView within it. I have not added the TextView using inflater. Now I want to use this LinearLayout multiple times in XMl layout. But the problem is that how can I set the text of these TextView within the LinearLayout?

Any ideas??

Comment: can you please post some part of your code that we can understand more :)

Comment: post some code and give more information.

Comment: you are adding textview programatically or through xml layout??

Comment: @AkashG I am adding programatically.

Comment: Let me make it clear. I am dynamically created a LinearLayout with a TextView inside it.
I am try to set the text of the TextVie in xml layout statically.

Answer (score 1):

If I right understand it will help you. Good luck!

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(id_linear_layout);
((TextView) layout.findViewById(id_textview)).setText("Text");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a reference of that TextView to to set the text.
Then add this TextView to LinearLayout.

ex -

```
TextView text = new TextView(yourActivity.this);
text.setText("Sample Text");
ll.addView(text);

// ll is your LinearLayout.
```

Answer (score 1):

When adding the `customTextView` set the tag using `setTag` method. And then to retrieve it use `linearLayout.findViewWithTag` method to retrieve the `customTextView` and as usual use `setText` to set the text

You an also alternatively set the `id` using `setId` and retrieve it using `findViewById` method

Comment: What you are talking about is doing every thing at dynamic level. What I am trying to do is to set the text in xml statically although my Linearlayout and textView is created dynamically.

Comment: Save the string as a resource in `string.xml` then

Comment: that is different. Consider the way during TextView declaration in XML we set android:Text="my text". The same way I want to set the text of the TextView which is contained within a linear Layout and the linearlayout with TextView is created custom in Java file.

Comment: ok then in the xml set the `android:tag` attribute of the `linearLayout` and then use use the `getTag` method of the linearLayout to get the tag and use that as the text for the textview